# how to change onmouseover attribute programmatic?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my html code is here.
   mouse event functions writing like this

```
<li class="gnb1" onmouseover="fn1('param_01');" onmouseout="fn2('param_02','param_01');" > ...
```

I want change function and parameters programmatical as jquery or javascript.

```
$("li.gnb1").attr("onmouseover", "new_function_name()");
```

this code is not working. help me. show your move!

Comment: you shouldn't use html attributes for event handlers if you can avoid it

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? Is `new_function_name` global? It works fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/R27tq/.

Comment: @Markasoftware sorry but I should use this html attributes.

Comment: if it's for a project at school or something where they require it, sure, but if it's not, then you should definitely use handlers added by js dynamically instead of attributes

Comment: @FelixKling yes, your code is works well. I try solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind the old handler and add a new one.

```
// To remove
$( "#foo").unbind( "click" );

// Then add new binding
$( "#foo").click(function () { });
```

Documentation for unbind is here:  http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

[Edit as per comment]

If you have the ability to change the HTML, you could use jQuery to perform your bindings as well as your unbindings.

[Further edit]

You can however remove an inline event handler with `removeAttr`

```
$('#foo').removeAttr('onclick');
```

Comment: I don't think `unbind` lets you remove inline event handlers.

Comment: You could simply use jQuery to bind the event handler as well :)

Comment: You should probably mention that in your answer. Also, the OP might not be able to modify the HTML.

Comment: I've edited as per your suggestion. :)

Comment: @FelixKling You are right, I have updated my answer to cover inline handlers.